# How to convert iBeacons UUID to MAC address?

Tags: python, bluetooth-lowenergy, decode, uuid

I have iBeacons UUID, major and minor parameters and I want to decode the MAC address of the beacon.

I have searched all over the internet and only version 1 UUID's have their MAC address in their UUID.
Is there any way I can decode UUID to get MAC address?
BLE scanner apps also display UUID, major, minor and MAC address of the beacon but beacon does not provide MAC address in its data.
Thanks.

Comment: The MAC address is sent with every Bluetooth packet and that is where the scanner gets it from.

Comment: I have parsed complete packet of iBeacon but there is no MAC address.

Comment: Can you tell us more about your usecase for the MAC address?